# How to interact programmatically with SSMS query & text editor?

Tags: ssms

Is there a means of interacting with the SQL Server Management Studio query and text editor?  An API or something?

I would like to be able to examine what's on there, even write code to it, programmatically.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on what are you trying to achieve? You can execute scripts or queries on RDBMS ( SQL Server in your case) using database connectors like JDBC via almost every language. Command line utilities are also available to execute code on a SQL Server instance provided you have login credentials and required permissions to perform the action.

Comment: SSMS is really just a re-badged Visual Studio - so I'm pretty sure you could extend SSMS with code snippets etc. Not sure to what extent those Visual Studio API's would be available (and operational) in SSMS, though ....